# RTK Query with Date- Range Picker, avoid unnecessary renders and abide rule of hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have a timecard component that in use could have large amounts of data per user and so it does not make sense to fetch the data until a date-range is supplied. With RTK Query, a hook is used to make the api call (e.x. {data: timecards, isLoading, isSuccess} = useGetTimecardsQuery(userId) ). Using the material ui Date-Range-Picker (or any date-range picker), the values are initially null or "" until the user selects the dates, which then sets the value. In order to delay the fetch, a common approach is to place the fetch into a function or hook to wait until the dates are selected and a button is pressed. However, since RTK Query uses a hook, it then breaks the rule of hooks by placing it not at the top level body of the component's function. I've tried making the search call it's own component and managed to not get any errors, but passing the component to the onClick fails to actually make the call.

Been digging around and not finding any discussion on this, and it could be theres something with React/ RTK that I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Timecard component: (all the commented out lines were different attempts at getting this to work)

```
export default function Timecard() {
    const { user } = useContext(UserContext)
    //const [isSearching, setIsSearching] = useState(false)
    //const isMounted = useIsMounted();

    // const [state, doFetch] = useAsyncFn(async () => {
    //  const response = await handleSearch();
    //  return response
    // }, [])

    

    const userId = user._id;

    //const { data: brackets, isLoading: isBracketsLoading, isSuccess: isBracketsSuccess } = useGetTimeBracketByUserIdQuery(userId);

    const [value, setValue] = useState(["", ""]);
    console.log({ value })

    // const [bracketState, setBracketState] = useState()
    // const [bracketLoad, setBracketLoad] = useState()
    // const [bracketSuccess, setBracketSuccess] = useState()


    const {
        data: visits,
        isLoading,
        isSuccess} = useGetVisitsByUserIdQuery(userId);


    // const handleSearch = (async () => {

    //  // if (isSearching) {
            

    //      let startDate = value[0];
    //      let endDate = value[1];

    //      const { data: brackets, isLoading: isBracketsLoading, isSuccess: isBracketsSuccess } = useGetBracketsOfUserByDateQuery(userId, startDate, endDate);
    //      setBracketState(brackets)
    //      setBracketLoad(isBracketsLoading)
    //      setBracketSuccess(isBracketsSuccess)
    //      .then(() => setIsSearching(false));
    //  // } else if (isMounted.current) {
    //  //  setIsSearching(false)
    //  // }
        
    // })

    // if (!isSearching) {
    //  setValue(["", ""])
    // } else if (isSearching) {
    //  handleSearch()
    // }

    // useEffect(() => {
    //  if (isSearching) {
    //      const effect = async () => {
    //          await handleSearch();
    //          if (!isMounted()) return;
    //          setIsSearching(false);
    //      };
    //      effect();
    //  }
    // }, [isSearching, isMounted, handleSearch]);

    let bracketInfo = <div><h3>Select dates above and click run to view time card info</h3></div>
    
    // if (bracketLoad) {
    //  bracketInfo = <div><h3>Loading...</h3></div>
    // } else if (bracketSuccess) {
    //  bracketInfo = 
    //  <div>
    //      <ul>
    //      {bracketState &&
    //          bracketState?.map((bracket) => (
    //              <TimeBracket key={bracket._id} bracket={bracket} /> 
    //          ))
    //      }
    //      </ul>
    //  </div>
    
    // }

    const handleClick = () => {
        <DateSearch value={[value]} />
    }

    return (
    <div>
    <h1>Timecard</h1> <AddTimeBracket />
    <br></br><br></br><br></br>
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
        <fieldset width='300px'>
            <legend>Select Date Range</legend>
        <DateRangePicker
            value={value}
            onChange={(newValue) => {
                setValue(newValue);
            }}
            renderInput={(startProps, endProps) => (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <TextField {...startProps} />
                    <Box sx={{ mx: 2}}> to </Box>
                    <TextField {...endProps} />
                </React.Fragment>
            )}
        />
        <Button onClick={() => handleClick()} color='primary' variant='contained'>
            Run 
        </Button>
        </fieldset>
    </LocalizationProvider>
    <br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br>
    
        
        <>
        {bracketInfo}
        
        </>
        
    
    </div>
    )
}
```

and the RTK Query being called in a child component to avoid breaking rule of hooks:

```
export default function DateSearch ([value]) {
    const [bracketState, setBracketState] = useState()
    const [bracketLoad, setBracketLoad] = useState()
    const [bracketSuccess, setBracketSuccess] = useState()

    let startDate = value[0];
    let endDate = value[1];

    const { data: brackets, isLoading: isBracketsLoading, isSuccess: isBracketsSuccess } = useGetBracketsOfUserByDateQuery(userId, startDate, endDate);
    setBracketState(brackets)
    setBracketLoad(isBracketsLoading)
    setBracketSuccess(isBracketsSuccess)
            
        
        
    let bracketInfo

    if (bracketLoad) {
        bracketInfo = <div><h3>Loading...</h3></div>
    } else if (bracketSuccess) {
        bracketInfo = 
        <div>
            <ul>
            {bracketState &&
                bracketState?.map((bracket) => (
                    <TimeBracket key={bracket._id} bracket={bracket} /> 
                ))
            }
            </ul>
        </div>
    
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

So 1 step in the right direction, but still broken. To resolve the render loop, adding a ternary operator for the initial state of value to set a status (isSearching), and giving it a fall back value [Date.now()] allows the component to load. To abide the rule of hooks and only call a hook in the body of the component, I moved the RTK Query call from the onClick function and had the onClick change the component status's state to trigger an if condition. However, now, once the onClick is triggered, the component breaks since an additional hook was called in the new render when compared to the previous render. So if anyone knows a way around this (or how to better structure the whole component so it works...), I'm grateful for any advice.

```
export default function Timecard() {
    const { user } = useContext(UserContext)
    const [isSearching, setIsSearching] = useState(false)

    const userId = user._id;

    const [value, setValue] = useState(isSearching ? [] : [new Date(), new Date()]);
    console.log({ value })  

    const [bracketState, setBracketState] = useState()
    const [bracketLoad, setBracketLoad] = useState()
    const [bracketSuccess, setBracketSuccess] = useState()


    function handleSearch() {

        setIsSearching(true)
        
    }

            
    if (isSearching) {
        let startDate = value[0];
        let endDate = value[1];

        const { data: brackets, isLoading: isBracketsLoading, isSuccess: isBracketsSuccess } = useGetBracketsOfUserByDateQuery(userId, startDate, endDate);
        setBracketState(brackets)
        setBracketLoad(isBracketsLoading)
        setBracketSuccess(isBracketsSuccess)
        setIsSearching(false)
    } 


    let bracketInfo = <div><h3>Select dates above and click run to view time card info</h3></div>
    
    if (bracketLoad) {
        bracketInfo = <div><h3>Loading...</h3></div>
    } else if (bracketSuccess) {
        bracketInfo = 
        <div>
            <ul>
            {bracketState &&
                bracketState?.map((bracket) => (
                    <TimeBracket key={bracket._id} bracket={bracket} /> 
                ))
            }
            </ul>
        </div>
    
    }


    return (
    <div>
    <h1>Timecard</h1> <AddTimeBracket />
    <br></br><br></br><br></br>
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
        <fieldset width='300px'>
            <legend>Select Date Range</legend>
        <DateRangePicker
            value={value}
            onChange={(newValue) => {
                setValue(newValue);
            }}
            renderInput={(startProps, endProps) => (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <TextField {...startProps} />
                    <Box sx={{ mx: 2}}> to </Box>
                    <TextField {...endProps} />
                </React.Fragment>
            )}
        />
        <Button onClick={() => handleSearch()} color='primary' variant='contained'>
            Run 
        </Button>
        </fieldset>
    </LocalizationProvider>
    <br></br><br></br>
    
        <>
        {bracketInfo}
        
        </>
        
    
    </div>
    )
}
```

**2nd UPDATE**
Ok, so setting the hook in the if condition breaks the rule of hooks as well. So with a bit of adjustment, the RTK call is now not breaking the rule of hooks, but cannot access the date range conditions because it is only running once... I'm at a loss of where to go.

```
export default function Timecard() {
    const { user } = useContext(UserContext)
    const [isSearching, setIsSearching] = useState(false)

    const userId = user._id;

    const [value, setValue] = useState(isSearching ? [] : [new Date(), new Date()]);
    console.log({ value })  

    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(value[0])
    const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(value[1])

    const [bracketState, setBracketState] = useState()
    const [bracketLoad, setBracketLoad] = useState()
    const [bracketSuccess, setBracketSuccess] = useState()

    //let startDate = value[0];
    //let endDate = value[1];
    const { data: brackets, 
            isLoading: isBracketsLoading, 
            isSuccess: isBracketsSuccess
    } = useGetBracketsOfUserByDateQuery(userId, startDate, endDate);


    function handleSearch() {

        setIsSearching(true)
        
    }

            
    if (isSearching) {
        

        
        setBracketState(brackets)
        setBracketLoad(isBracketsLoading)
        setBracketSuccess(isBracketsSuccess)
        setIsSearching(false)
    } 


    let bracketInfo = <div><h3>Select dates above and click run to view time card info</h3></div>
    
    if (bracketLoad) {
        bracketInfo = <div><h3>Loading...</h3></div>
    } else if (bracketSuccess) {
        bracketInfo = 
        <div>
            <ul>
            {bracketState &&
                bracketState?.map((bracket) => (
                    <TimeBracket key={bracket._id} bracket={bracket} /> 
                ))
            }
            </ul>
        </div>
    
    }


    return (
    <div>
    <h1>Timecard</h1> <AddTimeBracket />
    <br></br><br></br><br></br>
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
        <fieldset width='300px'>
            <legend>Select Date Range</legend>
        <DateRangePicker
            value={value}
            onChange={(newValue) => {
                setValue(newValue);
                setStartDate(newValue[0])
                setEndDate(newValue[1])
                console.log(startDate, endDate)
            }}
            renderInput={(startProps, endProps) => (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <TextField {...startProps} />
                    <Box sx={{ mx: 2}}> to </Box>
                    <TextField {...endProps} />
                </React.Fragment>
            )}
        />
        <Button onClick={() => handleSearch()} color='primary' variant='contained'>
            Run 
        </Button>
        </fieldset>
    </LocalizationProvider>
    <br></br><br></br>
    
        
        <>
        {bracketInfo}
        
        </>
        
    
    </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are going to very high lengths to either recreate

- `useLazyQuery` (which will not run before you call a function the first time),
- passing `skipToken` as an argument to the hook (which will make a query not run)
- setting the `skip` option on the hook call (which will not make the query run)

Have you looked into these?

Comment: Thanks! Thats exactly what I was looking for. Definitely got myself running around in circles and should have just gone back to the docs...